# Call JavaScript function after file download complete ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a ASP.NET MVC application where I am showing some files in a html table, in which the user can download the file by clicking on it.

There is a requirement, once the user downloads the file, the file record in the table should not be shown anymore. When the user downloads the file, I mark it as downloaded by the user in the backend table, and if I refresh the page then the record wont be shown on the grid since it is not coming from the backend anymore.

The problem that I am facing is, once I return the File from the controller I cannot figure out a way to run the refresh JavaScript Method. The download link in the html table is a anchor tag.

Can anyone please point me to a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Couldnt you just refresh the whole page from the controller action, or have the table as a Partial View and just refresh the partial view with Javascript?

Comment: the table is in a partial view. The controller return a FileStreamResult. I need to call the JavaScript function which refresh this partial view once the file is downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround solution for my problem. Below is the solution that I came up with after doing some searching.

1. Add a cookie to the response before the file is returned.
   [image]
2. When the file download starts, this cookie will be written to the browser. The file download is triggered when the user clicks on a anchor link on the page. So I then added a onclick event to the anchor tag and registered a JavaScript timer to run every 1 second using setInterval() method.
3. When the timer ticks, it will check for the above cookie in the browser. I used the library https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie to check and get the cookie.
4. If the cookie is present then I called my JavaScript function to refresh the html table and removed the cookie from the browser and then remove the JavaScript timer using clearInterval() method.
   [image]